# Creating a function has string variable in R

Tags: r, string, function, variables

My dataframe named Vietnamese_age is like this:

- Vietnamese_city: Hanoi Danang HCMcity ...
- Age_population_from 10_to_20: 10000 20000 15000 ...
- Age_population_from 20_to_30: 15000 25000 15000 ...
- Age_population_from 30_to_40: 14000 28000 14000 ...
- Age_population_from 40_to_50: 21000 26000 12000 ... and so on

There are too many of age period, so I'm going to make a function which has a string variable, so when i insert a certain string ("Age population from 10 - 20"), it will show the boxplot of this age group in certain city and the mean of whole country.

I have built the very first function:

```r
Age_function <- function(x) { mean(Vietnamese_age$x) }
```

and tried:

```r
x = "Age_population_from 10_to_20"
```

resulting in the following error:

> Error in Age_function(Age_population_from 10_to_20) : object 'Age_population_from 10_to_20' not found

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a sample of your data try `dput(Vietnamese_age)` or a representative subset to make you question a [reprex].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$`, we can use `[[`

```
Age_function <- function(x) mean(Vietnamese_age[[x]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

It is also better to provide data as argument

```
Age_function <- function(dat, x) mean(dat[[x]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

and then call

```
Age_function(Vienamese_age,  "Age_population_from 10_to_20")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made it. But how can I filter the name of the city. It means function (dat, x,y) when y is the name of the Vietnamese city. It seems that i can't use: dat %>% filter ( Vietnamese_city == y). Is there any alternative way? Thank you!